# TinyMCE- Get plain text

Tags: tinymce

In tinyMCE, Is there any way to get the plain text instead of HTML text?

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
var myText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({ format: 'text' });
```

Comment: worked without the .selection part, just `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' });`

Comment: I believe the `.selection` path only retrieves the text that the user has selected

Answer (score 7):

```
var rawtext = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().textContent;
```

Comment: problem with this one is that it converts the `<br>` to `''` or in other words to nothing. This will cause words to collapse such as `[...] end of line with not periodAnother paragraph`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this approach:

```
editor.getContent()
   .replace(/<[^>]*>/ig, ' ')
   .replace(/<\/[^>]*>/ig, ' ')
   .replace(/&nbsp;|&#160;/gi, ' ')
   .replace(/\s+/ig, ' ')
   .trim();
```

- Replaces both opening and closing html tags with space
- Replaces various known special characters with space (add yours as well)
- Replaces multiple spaces with a single space

Worked reasonably well, but it is obviously not perfect. I need only an approximation of plain text for purposes of word counting, so I am willing to ignore corner cases such as having part of the word bold or italic (replacement above for `<b>a</b><i>x</i>` will produce two separate words `a b` instead of `ab`).

It is an extension of [Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Beware regex for parsing HTML.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  The pony, he comes.