# Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string

Tags: html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags)

Is there an expression which will get the value between two HTML tags?

Given this:

```
<td class="played">0</td>
```

I am looking for an expression which will return `0`, stripping the `<td>` tags.

Comment: Is that the string, the whole string and nothing but the string? If so, how about `\d+`?

Comment: I'm using something like this: `(?:<style.+?>.+?</style>|<script.+?>.+?</script>|<(?:!|/?[a-zA-Z]+).*?/?>)` and replacing with `""`.

Comment: If you're reading this question, ***please*** read the accepted answer for the duplicate. The top two answers here are both vulnerable to a very simple input. TL;DR: regular expressions are ***not*** useful for properly stripping HTML tags.

Comment: ```<[^>]*>[^>]*<[^>]*>  ``` 

if you need to remove the context and HTML tag. example: ```hello<sub>2</sub> guys``` will be ```hello guys```

Comment: This regex ```<\/?\w[^>]*>|&\w+;``` requires a proper tag. Example: "3 <5  and  10 > 9" will not be removed and also remove html codes like &nbsp;

Answer (score 222):

You should not attempt to parse HTML with regex. HTML is not a regular language, so any regex you come up with will likely fail on some esoteric edge case. Please refer to the seminal answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) for specifics. While mostly formatted as a joke, it makes a very good point.

---

*The following examples are Java, but the regex will be similar -- if not identical -- for other languages.*

---

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Assuming your non-html does not contain any < or > and that your input string is correctly structured.

If you know they're a specific tag -- for example you know the text contains only `<td>` tags, you could do something like this:

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("(?i)<td[^>]*>", "");
```

Edit: 
Ωmega brought up a good point in a comment on another post that this would result in multiple results all being squished together if there were multiple tags.

For example, if the input string were `<td>Something</td><td>Another Thing</td>`, then the above would result in `SomethingAnother Thing`.

In a situation where multiple tags are expected, we could do something like:

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("(?i)<td[^>]*>", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

This replaces the HTML with a single space, then collapses whitespace, and then trims any on the ends.

Comment: The point here is to return match(es). If there would be more mathces in string, you will merge them to one mess string. Example: `<div>text</div><p>here</p>`. Got it?

Comment: You should not downvote me for comments. I didn't downvote you. I can proof it by downvoting you now, if you want to...

Comment: The OP said, "I am looking for an expression which will return 0, stripping the <td> tags." The title of the post is "regular expression to remove html tags from a string". I stripped the `<td>` tags. Nowhere in the OP did s/he mention anything about pattern *matching*.

Comment: You should or could use a RegEx version like this:
`string target = stringContainingHTMLTags.replace(/<[^>]*>/ig, "");`

Comment: @Netsi1964 How does that differ from the solutions already presented in the answer?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas My advice used the method `replace` which is a standard method, whereas "`replaceAll`" is a jQuery method working on DOM elements. Actually your solution will fail, trying to execute it on a string (not a DOM element). Do you see? :-)

Comment: @Netsi1964 - Actually my examples are Java and are executed on Strings. I have added a note to the answer indicating this.

Comment: Instead of * you could use +, because with * you will also replace <> if found in text. –

Comment: You *could*, but you shouldn't ever use regex to remove HTML tags from a string in the first place. ;-) And a > in  text should be `&gt;` anyway.

Comment: This is ***terrible*** advice - you could easily break this with `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" onload="$.getScript('evil.js');1<2>3">`, which is perfectly valid HTML (it displays a 1px GIF and loads a script assuming jQuery is present). Don't ever use regular expressions to strip HTML tags, especially if it's for any security reason.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you not understand the concept of duplicates? This question is closed.

Answer (score 94):

A trivial approach would be to replace

```
<[^>]*>
```

with nothing. But depending on how ill-structured your input is that may well fail.

Comment: Replacement is not good approach. For more matches you would merge them to one string.

Comment: I don't think I get what you're trying to say.

Comment: Given `<td>First</td><td>Second</td>`, using a `replaceAll` on the pattern in your post would result in `FirstSecond`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Indeed. But given `<b>a</b><i>b</i>` the result `ab` would be expected. So it's not something you could trivially decide. Besides, viewing XML in a browser causes the same, collapsing all text nodes together.

Comment: Try this against `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAA‌​QABAAACAkQBADs=" onload="$.getScript('evil.js');1<2>3">`. It won't correctly remove it at all. (This loads a 1px GIF, then assuming jQuery is present, loads a script.)

Comment: @IsiahMeadows: »But depending on how ill-structured your input is that may well fail.«.

Comment: Here's a regex which works well even for malformed html - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177854/4717533

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with jsoup http://jsoup.org/

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
String cleanStr = Jsoup.clean(yourText, whitelist);
```

Comment: JSoup is a very cool library, but unless the OP is planning on doing a lot more than just the simple replacement he's described in his original post it's probably a rather heavy weight solution.