# Converting XHTML to plain text

Tags: java, text, xhtml

Is there a way to  convert the XHTML to Plain text using Java?

Can any one please guide me on this?

Comment: You have to write some code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by XHTML to Plain text? XHTML is already a plain text file. Try open in an editor (Notepad).
Do you mean to remove all the tags ? Please provide more info

Comment: Suppose i have below XHTML, from that i need to extract the "Title" and "body" as plain text Is there a way to do that using Java / Unix script .                                                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Title of document</title>
</head>

<body>
Page source
<p>This is a test page.</p>
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

If you want extract special data from XHTML structure, try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's provide jquery-like methods to extracting and manipulating XHTML. You can iterate all html dom elements and get text attributes.

Or if you want remove html tags, and keep the text only, try using regular expressions. Look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string).