# Remove all attributes from Email stored in a clob using regexp_replace in PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, oracle11g

I have some Email content stored in a clob that I am outputting to a page using PLSQL. However, the underlying Email content has a number of attributes applied to the tags contained within such as

```
     <p style="*STYLE HERE*">
```

and

I wish to therefore process this clob using regexp_replace to remove all occurrences of style, class, _mce_style and width attributes that are applied to elements as well as the content within these attributes.

My question is, which regular expression do I used to do this?

I essentially need something like

```
    l_html_content := regexp_replace(email_clob, style" REMOVE ALL CONTENT" ,'')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string) about removing HTML tags.

Comment: @ThinkJet I've already solved this issue as you can see below but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok. And now you should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) if satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 l_html_content := regexp_replace(l_html_content,'\s(?:style|dir|height|width|class|align|color|face|size)\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*','');
```

Comment: This would truncate the e-mail to 32 kilobytes.