# javascript - string starts with an html tag

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest a way to tell if the first word in a string is an html tag?

At the moment, I am doing this:

```
var text = model.get('message');

try {
  $(text)[0];
} catch (_error) {
  text = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
}
```

But this seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to do exactly as is done by the library you're using (jQuery). Here's an extract from the source :

```
// A simple way to check for HTML strings
// Prioritize #id over <tag> to avoid XSS via location.hash (#9521)
// Strict HTML recognition (#11290: must start with <)
rquickExpr = /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/,
```

So you could simply do

```
 if (rquickExpr.test(text)) { // it's HTML
```

Note that there's no guarantee it's **really** valid HTML.