# HTML tags showing in page title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, title

I am setting page titles dynamically, based on the on a property in the page's model. Sometimes that property contains html tags, such as `<i>Article Title</i>`. When the property contains HTML tags, they are showing in the page title. I tried surrounding the property with `@Html.Raw`, but it didn't help. How can I make sure the tags don't show?

Code:

```
<head>
    <title>@Html.Raw(Model.Title)</title>
</head>
```

Working code based on [@Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532510/174718):

```
<head>
@{
    string titleRaw = Model.Title;
    string htmlTag = "<[^>]*>";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(htmlTag);
    string titleToShow = rgx.Replace(titleRaw, blank);
}
    <title>@titleToShow</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Html.Raw isn't going to eliminate the markup from your property.  You will need to scrub that out yourself.  In the past I have used separate properties for titles that shouldn't have markup in them.

Comment: If you combine regex and `Html.Raw`, you'll get the best of both. Clean and safe text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try to do it with regular expressions?

```
<[^>]*>
```

Took that from:

[Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

> Assuming your non-html does not contain any < or > and that your input
>   string is correctly structured.

A more complete explanation is available in above SO link