# Spring MVC code inject validator

Tags: spring, validation, sql-injection, code-injection

I have two fields, one that not allow save HTML tags on DB and the other allow.

[image]

How I create an validator that remove spetial chars and tags from my string before save, and apply on String fields only?

PS.: I need something to block SQL inject too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually validator cannot remove any chars. Validator just checks whether entered content is valid or not.

Read [for example](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator)

For your case you can define form fields and mar them with

```
@Pattern(regexp = "the detect html expression here")
```

See regular expressions to `[detect][2]` (and [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)) html