# Match all text except tags regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I have a string that has HTML tags i would like to use Regex to get rid all tags in my text. 
I've tried this pattern in my `js` code. But this one match all text within tags with chars `<` and `>`. How to get rid this chars `<` and `>`.
Thank you.

```
var input = document.getElementById("textarea");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.value;
var cont = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
var res = document.getElementById('result');
var contCopy = cont;
var newChar = cont.substr(cont.length - 1);
var g = cont.match("/>(?!\?(>|\s))[^<]+?</g");
res.value = g;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: This type of validation will break as soon as someone does `<foo attr=>bar />`. Look into parsing the HTML then just taking the text contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ