# How to remove HTML tags from column in redshift?

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have column in a redshift table like this:

```
col1

<span style='text-align: center; border: 1px solid #4cae4c; border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; padding: 30px 40px; display: inline-block; background-color: #2acf98; font-size: 16px !important;'>Great</span>

<b><strong>Pretty good!</strong></b>
```

As you can tell with these two rows, not all the HTML tags are the same. I only want, keep the data in between `> <`

The update column should look like this:

```
col1
Great
Pretty Good!
```

I tried this:

select 
REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '') as col1 
from table1

The column looks like this:

```
spanstyletextaligncenterborder1pxsolid4cae4cborderradius4pxcolorfffpadding30px40px displayinlineblockbackgroundcolor2acf98fontsize16pximportantGreat
```

Comment: Regex isn't well suited to manipulate nested HTML, which is what you have as your starting point.  You may want to export your data to a tool which can handle parsing HTML/XML, and do the replacement there.

Comment: got it, the data is coming from a python script. Is there anything in sql I can use to manipulate the text?

Comment: `<b><strong>Pretty good!</strong></b>` <-- this is the problem.  It is hard in a single go to tell a regex to extract what is beneath nested tags.  And your actual full data may have edge cases even uglier than this.  If you have only single level HTML tags, then a regex could be given perhaps.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '<[^<>]*>', '')` or `REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '<[^>]*>', '')` should work here.

Comment: This works but still leaves behind all whitespace and all HTML-encoded entities like `&nbsp;` or `&amp;`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked! If you answer I will accept.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229866/3832970).

Comment: @Wiktor See [my 2009 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/785743/18771). It's not a particularly good solution, but as a one-off on a limited and known data-set, it works.

Comment: @Tomalak Oh, that looks to be a pattern for some messed up HTML. Anyway, the current problem is solved.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why not to use '<.*?>'?

Comment: @Aurieli It is much less efficient.