# Grab anything between certain tags / specific data from html?

Tags: php, regex, curl

I have a custom-written eCommerce website - any my competition is playing quite unfair (at times) game. They play with their prices quite heavily, meaning if I lower or change a price for a product in a few days it's changed on my competitor pages.

What I wanted to do is to write a custom code in php for my admin section that would allow to query same product pages on competitor websites and just show me what prices they have for the same product.

I am able to run some curl and then I run into a problem. I played with regex, but unfortunately it doesn't really work the way I want. The problem is, I need a solution that would work for insance for 3 two cases on 3 different htmls, for example:

```
<span class="price">$322.00</span>
<div class="sale-price">322</div>
<div class="some_price"><span class="price" ...>$322 USD</span></div>
```

etc.

What's the way of getting regex (or if there's other way let me know please) to cut whatever goes between some certain html tags? I don't care if it's numbers or formatted price I just need it for comparison inside my own admin pricing tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of [Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string) .

Nevertheless, if you can execute curl commands, you might be able to also execute other terminal / CLI commands such as 'sed'. If it's the case, an easy way to remove most of the HTML tags is the following : 
`curl www.a-given-web-page.com | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'`

Actually, if you are not able to use sed, you could probably easily reuse the regex pattern I use in the sed command (`<[^>]*>`) in your php code ?
I'm not a PHP expert but it seems that a regular expression search and replace function does exist in PHP :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

I hope this will be useful, good luck !

Update : I checked a bit how to use preg_replace on a PHP sandbox.
It seems to work on your sample data :
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9f8dc6ac31c2f0505a9f2c29ee503c7d5c69e72

Here is how I would code it : `$result = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $string);`
(where `$string` is the variable where your html is stored, `$result` should contain the expected result without html tag).

Comment: preg-replace exists but I can't figure out how to extract anything between specific html tags as in examples above, prices doesn't matter in what format. I've searched the web all over but none of examples did work. thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: Again, I'm not very experienced with PHP but could you try the following :
`$result = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $string);`
where `$string` is the variable where your html is stored and `$result` should store the expected result