# Search in the database without considering HTML tags in MySql and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a record in the database as

```
I am <b>"Asking"</b> a question
```

in the column called log_message using

```
LogTable::where('log_message','like','%I am "Asking" a ques%')
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You must remove tags before compare.

Comment: Can you explain in breif?

Comment: MySql doesn't have a default function to strip html. You will need to store a custom function in MySql and then use it in raw query in Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest but performance-wise pretty costly way is to remove the HTML in your `log_message` column beforehand using MySQLs [`REGEXP_REPLACE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) (the RegEx coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230103/8394877)):

```
LogTable::whereRaw('regexp_replace(log_message, "<[^>]*>", "") like ?', '%I am "Asking" a ques%')
```

Alternatively if your're using MySQL 5.7+, you can add a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to your table with the same RegEx used in the raw where query above:

```
alter table
    logs_table
add column
    log_message_clean text as
    (
        regexp_replace(log_message, '<[^>]*>', '')
    );
```

or if you want to manually set the contents of your column manually (like in your code to have better control of what gets removed, with [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) for example), just add a new column and have your mode automatically update this column on every change where the base column `log_message` gets changed:

```
protected static function boot(): void
{
    self::creating(function (LogTable $model) {
        $model->log_message_clean = strip_tags($model->log_message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a Full Text Search if you're using InnoDB or MyISAM tables.

```
$search = "like','%I am \"Asking\" a ques%";
LogTable::whereRaw('match(log_message) against(?)', [$search])->get();
```

Then you'll need to add a Full Text index.

```
DB:statement('alter table log_table add fulltext fulltext_index(log_message)');
```

Comment: OP needs strict (char? byte?) match, whereas FTS have its own opinion what is it...

Comment: Where does it say he needs s strict match?  His example code uses a `like` statement with two wildcards.

Comment: Well, "strict substring match".