# How to replace HTML tags throughout file with string based on tag ID

Tags: html, regex, bash

I have a bunch of HTML files with empty `<a>` tags tied to unique page IDs. I'd like to replace each one with the same link but including the text of the ID visibly in the line (i.e. displayed within the `<p>...</p>` tags within which the `<a>` tags occur) and changing the class of the tag so I can format it in the CSS.

So what I have currently is tags like this occurring throughout text:

`<a id="page_123" class="garbage1"></a>some text<a id="page_124" class="garbage2"></a>`

And I want to replace it with:

`<a id="page_123" class="pagenum"> 123 </a>some text<a id="page_124" class="pagenum"> 124 </a>`

So that the resulting display is:

> some text **123** some text **124** some text.

The class of each of these tags is not always the same but I want to change all of them to pagenum. The tag id is always of the form page_####, anywhere from 1 to 4 digits.

I'm way over my head on this. I've gotten as far as constructing a horrifying regex (I know, I know) to pick the pattern out of the files, which seems to work when I test via `cat file1.html | grep -o "\Wa\sid..page.\d*.\sclass..\w*....a."`—that returns every instance of the pattern and nothing else. I'm totally stuck trying to go from there to making the replacement happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229866/4026227)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.  You will be sad and frustrated.  Get a proper HTML parser in the language you're using.  Use the parser to read in the HTML document into a DOM, make your changes in the DOM, and then write the HTML back out from that.

Comment: I was sad and frustrated before I started! I spent some time looking at a parser but for a one-off project like this it was going to be too much work. Next time around I'll start from the right place though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First handle the greedy `sed` by inserting newlines.

```sh
sed -r 's#</a>#&\n#g' file1.html
```

Next determine how strict your match should be

```sh
sed -r 's#</a>#&\n#g' file1.html |
   sed -r 's#(<a id="page_)([^"]*)(" class=")([^"]*).*#\1\2\3pagenum">\2</a>#'
```

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(<a\s+id="page_(\d+)"\s+class=").+?">/$1pagenum"> $2 /g' file.html
```

- The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp whole file to allow included line breaks.
- The regex `.+?` is used as a non-greedy match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sed -r 's/(id="page_([0-9]+)" +class=)"[^"]*">/\1"pagenum"> \2 /g' file1.html
```

This is finding the following expression:

```
(id="page_([0-9]+)" +class=)"[^"]*">
```

replacing it with:

```
\1"pagenum"> \2
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/btvAtl/2).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Oops! I always forget that `\d` is not accepted by `sed`. I edited the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858), but use a parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) or [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) instead.

Assuming *'input.htm'*:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p><a id="page_123" class="garbage1"></a>some text<a id="page_124" class="garbage2"></a></p>
  <p><a id="page_125" class="garbage1"></a>some text<a id="page_126" class="garbage2"></a></p>
  <p><a id="page_127" class="garbage1"></a>some text<a id="page_128" class="garbage2"></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

With `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -O -P \
  -u '//a' -x 'concat(" ",substring(@id,6)," ")' \
  input.htm
<html>
<body>
  <p><a id="page_123" class="garbage1"> 123 </a>some text<a id="page_124" class="garbage2"> 124 </a></p>
  <p><a id="page_125" class="garbage1"> 125 </a>some text<a id="page_126" class="garbage2"> 126 </a></p>
  <p><a id="page_127" class="garbage1"> 127 </a>some text<a id="page_128" class="garbage2"> 128 </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

With `xidel`:

```
$ xidel -s --input-format=xml input.htm -e '
  x:replace-nodes(
    //a,
    function($x){
      element a {$x/@*,x" {substring($x/@id,6)} "}
    }
  )
' --printed-node-format=xml
<html>
<body>
  <p><a id="page_123" class="garbage1"> 123 </a>some text<a id="page_124" class="garbage2"> 124 </a></p>
  <p><a id="page_125" class="garbage1"> 125 </a>some text<a id="page_126" class="garbage2"> 126 </a></p>
  <p><a id="page_127" class="garbage1"> 127 </a>some text<a id="page_128" class="garbage2"> 128 </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```