# How to remove the html-like part of a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I've got a string that looks like this:

```
<b><!--
</b>if (window!= top)
top.location.href=location.href
<b>// -->
</b>
15 Minutes
EMIL (V.O.)
Just do what I do.  Say the same thing I
say.  Don't open your mouth.
```

I only want the string starting from "15 minutes", and based on the answer to another question on SO I've tried using regex like this:

```
def cleanhtml(raw_text):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>.*?')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_text)
    return cleantext
```

But this does not clean the `"if (window!= top) top.location.href=location.href"` part of the string. What should I use for the regular expression then?

P.S.: I don't have an HTML file to begin with. The original datafile is already in `.txt` form.

Comment: HTML parsing is hard. Use a third party library such as `bleach`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string/11230103. The answers there go into more detail.

Comment: Generally speaking, parsing HTML with regular expressions is considered a bad idea (and may not even be possible). Another popular third-party library is named [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries already built to do exactly this.

To convert the text portion of the `html` you can use [`html2text`](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

```
import html2text

html = '''
<b><!--

</b>if (window!= top)

top.location.href=location.href

<b>// -->

</b>

15 Minutes

EMIL (V.O.)

Just do what I do.  Say the same thing I

say.  Don't open your mouth.
'''

text_maker = html2text.HTML2Text() 
text_maker.strong_mark = False ##This prevents **** being added for <b>
text_maker.handle(html)

#"15 Minutes EMIL (V.O.) Just do what I do. Say the same thing I say. Don't open\nyour mouth.\n\n"
```

If you need to specify specific `divs` or `classes` you will need to use something like `BeautifulSoup`