# TinyMCE getContent giving encoded URLs

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I have a page with a TinyMCE textarea for taking some input.
When a user types in a content like

```
#WorldCupRio http://www.ball.com/us/experience?story=hello&city=panama
```

and i do a

```
jTextarea.tinymce().getContent()
```

on it, i get a content like

```
#WorldCupRio http://www.ball.com/us/experience?story=hello&amp;city=panama
```

the & is encoded to

```
&amp;
```

How can i avoid this encoding with & or any other special character? Pls help.

Comment: do you try `verify_html:false`

Comment: no, i dont want verify_html. i don't want users to copy paste messages and take that html.

Comment: i want users to type their messages. and that message can have links. i just want the message i get from tinymce to not be encoded & should not be &amp

Comment: this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288083/tinymce-get-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

This should actually be set up during the init phase of the editor.

```
tinyMCE.init({
     entity_encoding: "raw",
     editor_selector: "tinyMCE",
     relative_urls : false,
     convert_urls : false
    // other config ...
}
```

You can check out [TinyMce configuration](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/)

**UPDATE**: it turns out that according to [entity_encoding config](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:entity_encoding), it is not possible to leave < > & ' and " as raw. Hence, the way I see it is to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to get back these raw entities.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the editor does the right thing.

If the URL would have been the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag, it would not be HTML encoded.

Did you try this plugin? Seems  like a good fit.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autolink/

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
   tinymce.init({
       entity_encoding : "raw"
    });
```

**Or** if your still having issues, you could try something like; basically removing *or* replacing certain characters of a string, or in this case, your URL; which you could first grab and *then* sanitize with something like below..

```
cleanURI = crappyURI.replace(&amp;, ''); // find unwanted characters and then remove
```

*then* use `.getContent();` to grab clean URL.

*Also check out [encodeURIComponent() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)*

Comment: Actually thats exactly what i'm doing, but i'm looking for something that is configurable :) :)

Comment: Great! can you describe more your desired configuration? And I can try to help more ;)

Comment: Seems we have no choice apart from replacing `&amp;`, I was looking for some options in configuration so that to avoid this replacing part. :p

Comment: I have to stay with this replace thing.